# 259 / 5000 Wyniki tłumaczenia Search engine - disappearing items from the status array

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with the search engine, it doesn't work properly. When I type some text into input, it searches for something, but when I delete it, all elements disappear. Please help.
State contains names taken from api

```
const courseReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
 case 'SEARCH':
                return state.filter(task => task.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(action.searchText))
}
}
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(courseReducer, [])
```

Form.jsx

```
const Form = () => {
    const { dispatch, state } = useContext(DataContext)
    const [text, setText] = useState('')

    const handleInput = event => {
        setText(event.target.value)
        const searchText = text.toLocaleLowerCase();
        dispatch({ type: 'SEARCH', searchText })
    }
return (
<input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleInput} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `courseReducer` is actually mutating the state after searching. What you want is to do the `filter` in the `Form` render itself.